# Installing Lazarus 1.6 on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, lazarus

I wish to install Lazarus 1.6.2 on ubuntu 16.04.
All the help I can find so far is either out of date, doesn't work, or is far more complicated than I am capable of.  Is there someone who has an understandable answer please.
Bill

Comment: Instructions at this Lazarus homepage seem to be very clear to me: http://www.lazarus-ide.org/

Comment: pick up the `.deb` file [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/lazarus/files/Lazarus%20Linux%20amd64%20DEB/Lazarus%201.6.2/) and just install as usual no complicated stuff

Answer (score 1):

Actually since Ubuntu 16.04. it is very easy to install Lazarus. Just open the terminal (for example with keys: ctrl + alt + T) and type in:

sudo apt-get install lazarus

Type your root - password and the lazarus-package will be installed.

## Important hint:

You can find every available Ubuntu-package under

https://packages.ubuntu.com/

A package with the name PACKEGENAME for example can be installed by typing in the terminal:

sudo apt-get install PACKEGENAME